# How to make g++ generate warning when extern variable declared differently in other file?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, extern

I have two files:

a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[100];

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

b.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern double a[50];
```

Apparently there is a conflict declaration of "a" in two files. But when I run

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp
```

The compilation silently succeeds.

Is there any way that I can make g++ complain about the conflict (either through a warning or an error)?

I tried the -Wshadow and -Wshadow-all flag. They didn't help.

Comment: did you try -Wshadow ?

Comment: Also, adding on, there is `-Wshadow=global`, `local`, or `compatible-local`, so you can fine-tune it as need be. Still, don't use namespaces globally. Or in general, ideally.

Answer (score 2):

One way to detect this is to always put `extern` declarations in a header (`.h`) file, and to include this file in the source module that defines those variables.

If you create an "a.h" file, this can be included in both "a.cpp" and "b.cpp".  The ensuing compilation would result in an error because the types don't match between the `extern double a[50];` declaration in the header and the `int a[50];` definition in "a.cpp".

Answer (score 0):

With recent enough versions of gcc, you can use `-flto` flag to both the compiler and linker. This invokes link-time optimization, which in some cases does catch type mismatches between `extern` variables.

You can also help with avoiding this problem by making sure that any names of external linkage are declared in header files.  If `extern double a[50];` had appeared in a common header included by `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` you would have gotten a compilation error for `a.cpp`.

Note that this is not "shadowing", which is why the shadow flags didn't help. Shadowing is when you re-use the same name in an inner scope where the name already existed in an outer scope, e.g. `void f() { int x;  { double x; } }`.  However , two different translation units are not overlapping scopes.

Answer (score 0):

From the g++ "point of view" there isn't a conflict. 
Variable `double a[50]` is constrained inside b.cpp file. As `a` exists in a.cpp, you have the, erroneous, perception that you're using the same variable. 
Declare another one, say, `int b` in b.cpp an try to use it in a.cpp, the linker will complain:

**b.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern char a[50];
extern int b;
```

**a.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[100];

int main() {
    b=3; //using a variable unknown by this scope
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

When compile, you'll get:

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:7:5: error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
     b=3;
     ^
```

Global variables has external linkage by default, so the `external` before the declaration are pretty ignored and what you have is a declaration of another variable of type double. Thus, for the linker, `double a[50]` is a variable totally separated from the one  declared in a.cpp because they are in separated scopes and there is no conflict, so no complain.